# How to send an email with a CSV attachment from a string

Tags: php, email

Here is my attempt at it can you let me know what I am doing wrong?

allputcsv converts the array into a csv formatted string. That is then base64 encoded and chunk split, this seems to work for normal files but is there something different I should do because I am using a string?

```
<?php

function sputcsv($row, $delimiter = ',', $enclosure = '"', $eol = "\n")
{
    static $fp = false;
    if ($fp === false)
    {
        $fp = fopen('php://temp', 'r+');
    }
    else
    {
        rewind($fp);
    }

    if (fputcsv($fp, $row, $delimiter, $enclosure) === false)
    {
        return false;
    }

    rewind($fp);
    $csv = fgets($fp);

    if ($eol != PHP_EOL)
    {
        $csv = substr($csv, 0, (0 - strlen(PHP_EOL))) . $eol;
    }
    return $csv;
}

function allputcsv($arr) {
    $str = "";
    foreach($arr as $val) {
        $str .= sputcsv($val);
    }
    return $str;
}

function send_mail($arr) {
    $to = 'youraddress@example.com'; 
    $subject = 'Test email with attachment'; 
    $random_hash = md5(date('r', time())); 
    $headers = "From: webmaster@example.com\r\nReply-To: webmaster@example.com"; 
    $headers .= "\r\nContent-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"--".$random_hash."\""; 
    $attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(allputcsv($arr))); 
    ob_start();
    ?> 
    --<?php echo $random_hash; ?>  
    Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1; format=flowed
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

    Hello World!!! 
    This is simple text email message. 

    --<?php echo $random_hash; ?>  
    Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel;
     name="test.csv"
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
    Content-Disposition: attachment;
     filename="test.csv"

    <?php echo $attachment; ?> 
    --<?php echo $random_hash; ?>-- 

    <?php 
    $message = ob_get_clean(); 
    $mail_sent = @mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers ); 
}

$array = array(array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7),array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7),array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7));

send_mail($array);
?>
```

Notes: I have to use the mail function I don't have a choice (I could use a wrapper but I would prefer not to) and I cant save the file on the server side.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can wrap the CSV creation code into a single function easily in a much shorter and more efficient way.

The correct MIME type for CSV files is `text/csv`. Also, you should use string concatenation and explicit `\r\n` sequences, since RFCs call for CRLF line separations and by using heredoc/nowdoc/output buffering with literal new lines, you will end up with 2 problems:

1. Your indentation may screw up the message format
2. Copying the file via FTP in ASCII mode may break the line endings

Try this instead:

```
function create_csv_string($data) {

  // Open temp file pointer
  if (!$fp = fopen('php://temp', 'w+')) return FALSE;

  // Loop data and write to file pointer
  foreach ($data as $line) fputcsv($fp, $line);

  // Place stream pointer at beginning
  rewind($fp);

  // Return the data
  return stream_get_contents($fp);

}

function send_csv_mail ($csvData, $body, $to = 'youraddress@example.com', $subject = 'Test email with attachment', $from = 'webmaster@example.com') {

  // This will provide plenty adequate entropy
  $multipartSep = '-----'.md5(time()).'-----';

  // Arrays are much more readable
  $headers = array(
    "From: $from",
    "Reply-To: $from",
    "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$multipartSep\""
  );

  // Make the attachment
  $attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(create_csv_string($csvData))); 

  // Make the body of the message
  $body = "--$multipartSep\r\n"
        . "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1; format=flowed\r\n"
        . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n"
        . "\r\n"
        . "$body\r\n"
        . "--$multipartSep\r\n"
        . "Content-Type: text/csv\r\n"
        . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n"
        . "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"file.csv\"\r\n"
        . "\r\n"
        . "$attachment\r\n"
        . "--$multipartSep--";

   // Send the email, return the result
   return @mail($to, $subject, $body, implode("\r\n", $headers)); 

}

$array = array(array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7), array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7), array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7));

send_csv_mail($array, "Hello World!!!\r\n This is simple text email message.");
```

Comment: Thank you very much I got it all working perfectly now. (on the last line send_mail should be send_csv_mail though)

Comment: Thank you very much! I was going at this problem the completely wrong way and this solved everything!

Comment: the data doesnt send for me

Comment: you just saved me bro.

Answer (score 2):

This is a simpler solution to create the csv I use to email attachments with phpmailer.

```
$csvinfo .= "$row[0],$row[1],$row[2],$row[3]\n";
$attachment = "details.csv";  
file_put_contents($attachment, $csvinfo, LOCK_EX);
```

and the relevant phpmailer lines to send an email with attachment

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();             // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'x';           // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;       // Enable SMTP     authentication
$mail->Username = 'xx';       // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'xx';         // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';     // Enable TLS or SSL also accepted
$mail->Port = 587;               // TCP port to connect to
$mail->setFrom('me@madein.us', 'Lily');
$mail->AddAddress("you@madein.us");
$mail->addAttachment($attachment);         // Add attachments
$mail->isHTML(true);             // Set email format to HTML
$mail->Subject = "Report";
$mail->Body    = $message;

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't say simpler. In this solution you safe the file to disk first (so you need a location to safe the file to and remove it after that) and you need to install an external library.

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this code. It works perfect.**

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'databasename');
if (!$con)
{
    die("error" . mysqli_connect_error());
}

error_reporting(E_ERROR);
$filename = "menu_list";
$sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM menu_list");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
$filename2='datas/'.$filename.'.csv';
$fp = fopen($filename2, "w");
$seperator = "";
$comma = "";
foreach ($row as $name => $value){$seperator .= $comma . '' . str_replace('', '""', $name);$comma = ",";}
$seperator .= "\n";
$seperator;
fputs($fp, $seperator);
mysqli_data_seek($sql, 0);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))
{
    $seperator = "";
    $comma = "";
    foreach ($row as $name => $value){$seperator .= $comma . '' . str_replace('', '""', $value);$comma = ",";}
    $seperator .= "\n";
    fputs($fp, $seperator);
}

fclose($fp);

$my_file = $filename2;
$path = "datas/";
$from_name = "solomon";
$from_mail = "pss@gmail.com";
$mailto = "pssworkcse@gmail.com";
$subject = "This is a mail with attachment.";
$message = "Hi,\r\n do you got attachment?\r\n\r\Solomon";
$replyto = "pssworkcse@gmail.com";
$file = $my_file;
$file_size = filesize($file);
$handle = fopen($file, "r");
$content = fread($handle, $file_size);
fclose($handle);
$content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
$uid = md5(uniqid(time()));
$name = basename($file);
$header = "From: " . $from_name . " <" . $from_mail . ">\r\n";
$header .= "Reply-To: " . $replyto . "\r\n";
$header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"" . $uid . "\"\r\n\r\n";
$header .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";
$header .= "--" . $uid . "\r\n";
$header .= "Content-type:text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
$header .= $message . "\r\n\r\n";
$header .= "--" . $uid . "\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"" . $filename2 . "\"\r\n"; 
$header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $filename2 . "\"\r\n\r\n";
$header .= $content . "\r\n\r\n";
$header .= "--" . $uid . "--";
mail($mailto, $subject, "", $header)

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**In my case i'm sending mail using laravel (v7) swift mailer.**

```
public function build(): SendMonthlyAbsenceReportToEmployee
{
    $body = "\r\n{$this->prepareFile()}\r\n";

    return $this->view('admin.mail.monthly-absence-report')
        ->with('employee', $this->employee)
        ->attachData($body, 'report.csv', [
            'mime' => 'text/csv'
        ])
        ;
}

private function prepareFile()
{
    $data = $this->service->sendEachEmployeeMonthlyAbsenceReport();

    $header = ['Date', 'Other Info'];

    $df = fopen('php://memory','rw');

    fputcsv($df, ["Name: Sohag", 'Designation: abc', 'Department: new department']);

    fputcsv($df, []);

    fputcsv($df, $header);

    foreach ($data as $row) {
        fputcsv($df, $row);
    }

    rewind($df);

    return stream_get_contents($df);
}
```